# Having trouble routing to a page that will update a data entry by making get request using data object's ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I'm trying to route a page to my project that will allow the user to edit an existing data entry within a MongoDB database, however I am getting this error. The intended function of the program is that a user will be able to select an edit button on a specific data entry, which will open a form allowing them to altar that entry's content. It should do this by making a get request using the data's ID, however there is something wrong happening when I try to concatenate the route string, and the data's ID. Here is my Main.js file, my VehiclesList.js file, and my EditVehicles.js file:

Main.js

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import VehicleList from "../VehicleList/index";
import AddVehicle from "../addVehicle/index";
import EditVehicle from "../editVehicle";

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<VehicleList />} />
          <Route path="/list" element={<VehicleList />} />
          <Route path="/addVehicle" element={<AddVehicle />} />
          <Route path="/editVehicle/:id" element={<EditVehicle />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

VehiclesList.js

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import VehicleService from "../services/services";

class VehicleList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.VehicleService = new VehicleService();
    this.state = {
      vehicles: [],
    };
    this.deleteVehicle = this.deleteVehicle.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getVehicleList();
  };

  //get all vehicles
  getVehicleList() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/vehicles")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({
          vehicles: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  //delete vehicle
  deleteVehicle(vehicleId) {
    this.VehicleService.deleteVehicle(vehicleId);
    this.getVehicleList();
    window.location.reload(false);
  }

  render() {
    const { vehicles } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="vehicleList">
        <table className="vehicleList_table">
          <thead>
            <tr className="vehicleList_table_head">
              <th className="vehicleList_table_head_title">#</th>
              <th className="vehicleList_table_head_title">Make</th>
              <th className="vehicleList_table_head_title">Model</th>
              <th className="vehicleList_table_head_title">Year</th>
              <th className="vehicleList_table_head_title">Price</th>
              <th className="vehicleList_table_head_title">Status</th>
              <th className="vehicleList_table_head_title"></th>
              <th className="vehicleList_table_head_title"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className="vehicleList_table_body">
            {vehicles &&
              vehicles.map((vehicle, idx) => {
                let status = "";
                if (vehicle.isSold) {
                  status = "Sold";
                } else {
                  status = "Available";
                }
                return (
                  <tr key={idx}>
                    <td className="vehicleList_table_item">{vehicle._id}</td>
                    <td className="vehicleList_table_item">{vehicle.make}</td>
                    <td className="vehicleList_table_item">{vehicle.model}</td>
                    <td className="vehicleList_table_item">{vehicle.year}</td>
                    <td className="vehicleList_table_item">{vehicle.price}</td>
                    <td className="vehicleList_table_item">{status}</td>
                    <td className="vehicleList_table_item">
                      <Link
                        to={"/editVehicle/" + vehicle._id}
                        style={{ fontSize: "1.5rem" }}
                        className="edit_btn"
                      >
                        edit
                      </Link>
                    </td>
                    <td className="vehicleList_table_item">
                      <button
                        onClick={() => this.deleteVehicle(vehicle._id)}
                        className="delete_btn"
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default VehicleList;
```

EditVehicles.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class EditVehicle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      make: "",
      model: "",
      year: "",
      price: "",
      isSold: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getVehicleById();
  };

  //get vehicle by ID
  getVehicleById() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://localhost:5000/vehicles/editVehicle/" +
          this.props.match.params.id
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          make: res.data.make,
          model: res.data.model,
          year: res.data.year,
          price: res.date.price,
          isSold: res.data.isSold,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  //handle changes to data
  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  //update record on submit
  submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { make, model, year, price, isSold } = this.state;
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:5000/vehicles/editVehicle/" +
          this.props.match.params.id,
        {
          make: make,
          model: model,
          year: year,
          price: price,
          isSold: isSold,
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.props.history.push("/");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="editVehicle">
        <form className="editVehicle_form" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <Link to="/" className="back_btn">
            Back
          </Link>

          <h1>Update Vehicle Details</h1>
          <p>Please fill out all fields</p>
          <input
            name="make"
            placeholder="Make"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.make}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
            className="editVehicle_form_input"
          />
          <br />
          <input
            name="model"
            placeholder="Model"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.model}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
            className="editVehicle_form_input"
          />
          <br />
          <input
            name="year"
            placeholder="Year"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.year}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
            className="editVehicle_form_input"
          />
          <br />
          <input
            name="price"
            placeholder="Price"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.price}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
            className="editVehicle_form_input"
          />
          <br />
          <label className="addVehicle_form_radio_label">
            Available
            <input
              name="isSold"
              type="radio"
              value={false}
              onChange={this.changeHandler}
              className="editVehicle_form_radio"
            />
          </label>
          <label className="editVehicle_form_radio_label">
            Sold
            <input
              name="isSold"
              type="radio"
              value={true}
              onChange={this.changeHandler}
              className="editVehicle_form_radio"
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Save" className="editVehicle_submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditVehicle;
```

My Routes to the VehiclesList, AddVehicle and DeleteVehicle pages all work. the only issue I'm running into is routing the EditVehicle page.

at first I was getting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined('params'), and then I changed the route to the EditVehicles page to this:

```
<Route path="/editVehicle/:id" component={EditVehicle} />
```

when I did it this way, I got an error back saying that this route did not have an element, and would result in an empty page.

I also tried doing it this way:

```
<Route path='/editVehicle/:id render={(props) => <EditVehicle {...props} />} />
```

this too just gave me an error saying that the route did not have an element.

is there an issue in my code that I am not seeing? or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You're using react router v6 but following v5 documentation. Please always google error messages first.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you, that you don't have `element` attribute in Route:

```
<Route path="/editVehicle/:id" component={EditVehicle} />
```

Replace `component` to `element`

```
<Route path="/editVehicle/:id" element={<EditVehicle/>} />
```

You messed up with different versions of React-router-dom implementations.
see [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

Try to add [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params#useparams) hook from React-router-dom in your EditVehicle component to get id:

```
let { id } = useParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The "edit vehicle" route is correct:

```
<Route path="/editVehicle/:id" element={<EditVehicle />} />
```

The issue is that in `react-router-dom@6` there are no longer any route props. In other words, `EditVehicle` is a class-based component and `this.props.match` and `this.props.history` are undefined. It's only when the code attempts to access into this undefined object (*i.e. `this.props.match.params`*) that the error is thrown.

Additionally, the `history` object is no longer directly exposed in RRDv6, you'll need to use the `useNavigate` hook to access a `navigate` function.

## Solution

You can either convert `EditVehicle` to a React function component or create a new custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component so that the route path params can be injected as props like the class component is expecting.

- Using custom `withRouter` HOC

  Create a `withRouter` HOC that can use the React hooks and inject new props for the class component to access.

  ```
   import { useNavigate, useParams, /* other hooks */ } from 'react-router-dom';

   const withRouter = Component => props => {
     const navigate = useNavigate();
     const params = useParams();
     // ... other hooks ...
     return (
       <Component
         {...props}
         {...{ navigate, params, /* other props from hooks */ }}
       />
     );
   };
  ```

  Decorate the `EditVehicle` component export:

  ```
   import withRouter from '../path/to/withRouter';

   ...

   export default withRouter(EditVehicle);
  ```

  `params` and `navigate` (*and others*) are now injected as props, access accordingly in `EditVehicle`:

  ```
   // get vehicle by ID
   getVehicleById() {
     const { params: { id } } = this.props;

     axios.get("http://localhost:5000/vehicles/editVehicle/" + id)
       .then((res) => {
         const { data: { make, model, year, price, isSold } } = res;
         this.setState({ make, model, year, price, isSold });
       })
       .catch(console.log);
   }

   // update record on submit
   submitHandler = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const { make, model, year, price, isSold } = this.state;
     const { navigate, params: { id } } = this.props;

     axios
       .post(
         "http://localhost:5000/vehicles/editVehicle/" + id,
         { make, model, year, price, isSold }
       )
       .then((res) => {
         console.log(res);
         navigate("/");
       })
       .catch(console.log);
   };
  ```
- Conversion to React function component

  - Use the `useNavigate` and `useParams` hooks directly
  - Use `React.useState` to store the form field values
  - use `React.useEffect` to update the state when the `id` path param updates
  - Convert all class methods to functions, and remove references to `this`

  Code:

  ```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
   import axios from "axios";
   import { Link, useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

   const EditVehicle = () => {
     const navigate = useNavigate();
     const { id } = useParams();

     const [state, setState] = useState({
       make: "",
       model: "",
       year: "",
       price: "",
       isSold: ""
     });

     useEffect(() => {
       // get vehicle by ID
       const getVehicleById = (id) => {
         axios
           .get("http://localhost:5000/vehicles/editVehicle/" + id)
           .then((res) => {
             const { make, model, year, price, isSold } = res.data;
             setState({ make, model, year, price, isSold });
           })
           .catch(console.log);
       };

       getVehicleById(id);
     }, [id]);

     //handle changes to data
     const changeHandler = (e) => {
       const { name, value } = e.target;
       setState((state) => ({
         ...state,
         [name]: value
       }));
     };

     //update record on submit
     const submitHandler = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       const { make, model, year, price, isSold } = state;
       axios
         .post("http://localhost:5000/vehicles/editVehicle/" + id, {
           make,
           model,
           year,
           price,
           isSold
         })
         .then((res) => {
           console.log(res);
           navigate("/");
         })
         .catch(console.log);
     };

     return (
       <div className="editVehicle">
         <form className="editVehicle_form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
           <Link to="/" className="back_btn">
             Back
           </Link>

           <h1>Update Vehicle Details</h1>
           <p>Please fill out all fields</p>
           <input
             name="make"
             placeholder="Make"
             type="text"
             value={state.make}
             onChange={changeHandler}
             className="editVehicle_form_input"
           />
           <br />
           <input
             name="model"
             placeholder="Model"
             type="text"
             value={state.model}
             onChange={changeHandler}
             className="editVehicle_form_input"
           />
           <br />
           <input
             name="year"
             placeholder="Year"
             type="text"
             value={state.year}
             onChange={changeHandler}
             className="editVehicle_form_input"
           />
           <br />
           <input
             name="price"
             placeholder="Price"
             type="text"
             value={state.price}
             onChange={changeHandler}
             className="editVehicle_form_input"
           />
           <br />
           <label className="addVehicle_form_radio_label">
             Available
             <input
               name="isSold"
               type="radio"
               value={false}
               onChange={changeHandler}
               className="editVehicle_form_radio"
             />
           </label>
           <label className="editVehicle_form_radio_label">
             Sold
             <input
               name="isSold"
               type="radio"
               value={true}
               onChange={changeHandler}
               className="editVehicle_form_radio"
             />
           </label>
           <br />
           <input type="submit" value="Save" className="editVehicle_submit" />
         </form>
       </div>
     );
   };
  ```